# Profile command (Need a bit of help)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Right, so I have this profile command. Before I attempted to add more to it, it worked. However, after attempting to add the discriminator and mutual guilds option it stopped working. The documentation uses the code I use but it doesn't work.

```
@commands.command()
async def profile(self, ctx, *, user: discord.Member):
    em = discord.Embed(title=f"Profile of {user}", color=0xeb0000)
    em.set_thumbnail(url = user.avatar_url)
    em.add_field(name="Nickname", value=f'{user.nick}', inline=True)
    em.add_field(name="Joined at", value=f'{user.joined_at}', inline=True)
    em.add_field(name="ID", value=f'{user.id}', inline=True)
    em.add_field(name="Discrim", value=f'{user.discriminator}', inline=True)
    em.add_field(name="Mutual Guilds", value=f'{user.mutual_guilds}', inline=True)
    em.set_footer(text="\nGOD", icon_url="https://i.imgur.com/Zfh8Una.jpg")
    em.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    await ctx.send(embed = em)
```

Working code:

```
@commands.command()
async def profile(self, ctx, *, user: discord.Member):
    em = discord.Embed(title=f"Profile of {user}", color=0xeb0000)
    em.set_thumbnail(url = user.avatar_url)
    em.add_field(name="Nickname", value=f'{user.nick}', inline=True)
    em.add_field(name="Joined at", value=f'{user.joined_at}', inline=True)
    em.add_field(name="ID", value=f'{user.id}', inline=True)
    await ctx.send(embed = em)
```

Any ideas and or help? Specifically, I want to add the discrim and mutual guilds option, along with the hypesquad house, however that didn't work either.

Comment: Which error comes up?

Comment: don't you see error message when you run code in console/terminal? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: why do you use `em` and later `embed` ? maybe it should be always `em. Besides you could use `print()` to see in console what lines of code are executed and what you have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"`

Comment: for single string you can use `value=user.nick` instead of using `f-strings` like `value=f'{user.nick}'`

Comment: @Dominik i'm not getting any errors

Answer (score 1):

1. In your `set_footer`, you did `emb.set_footer`. This would raise the error `NameError: name 'emb' is not defined`, so you will want to change it to `em.set_footer`
2. In your `em.timestamp`, it is likely that you would receive the error `AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'`. For the time being, I recommend using `datetime.utcnow()`, which should do about the exact same thing.
3. `user.mutual_guilds` returns a `guild object`, and the problem with that is that with each guild you'll get something similar to the following: `[<Guild id=778530777729335316 name='Friends of Mara' shard_id=1 chunked=True member_count=29>, <Guild id=747061937673732097 name='Blitz Support' chunked=True member_count=18>...etc`. Since you may only want the names of each guild, you will have to iterate through the list provided.
4. Let's say your bot is in 100 servers. If someone were to go `!profile @yourbot`, it is very likely that there would be too many mutual guilds. However, I won't explain how to combat this here.

Also, as a side note, do check if your error-handler is 'eating up' your errors. While testing this, I had received multiple errors as described above, so make sure you do just that.

The revised code is as follows:

```py
@client.command()
async def test(ctx, *, user: discord.Member=None): # included this None as an extra in case user doesn't mention anyone
    if user == None:
        user = ctx.author # so if the user didn't mention anyone, the ctx.author becomes the user
    em = discord.Embed(title=f"Profile of {user}", color=0xeb0000)
    em.set_thumbnail(url = user.avatar_url)
    # following furas' comment, you don't need the f-strings for single strings
    # but if you do, it will not break the code
    em.add_field(name="Nickname", value=f'{user.nick}', inline=True)
    em.add_field(name="Joined at", value=f'{user.joined_at}', inline=True)
    em.add_field(name="ID", value=f'{user.id}', inline=True)
    em.add_field(name="Discrim", value=f'{user.discriminator}', inline=True)

    # new part #
    guild_list = [] # create a new empty list
    for guild in user.mutual_guilds: # for every guild the bot and the user shares..
        guild_list.append(str(guild.name)) # append the name to the guild_list
    # str(guild.name) is important, otherwise you'll get an error of:
    # TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, Guild found
    em.add_field(name="Mutual Guilds", value=f"{', '.join(guild_list)}", inline=True)
    ##

    em.set_footer(text="\nGOD", icon_url="https://i.imgur.com/Zfh8Una.jpg")
    em.timestamp = datetime.utcnow() # changed it to datetime.utcnow()
    await ctx.send(embed = em)
```

Here is the code working as expected:
[image: Code working as expected]

Comment: I took your code and attempted to implement it into my cog, I haven't gotten any errors but it still didn't work for me. Did you import anything I might not have? Thank you :)

Comment: @VCtrl I haven't imported anything extra as far as I'm concerned. Are other commands in your cog working? Do you have an error handler that could be 'eating' all your errors?

Comment: all other commands are working, and my error handler might be eating all of them but I'm not exactly sure how to print it off.

Comment: @VCtrl my suggestion would be to create another question, specifically about your error handler. You can also have a look at how other's ensure errors aren't eaten up, such as [EvieePy's error_handler.py on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/EvieePy/7822af90858ef65012ea500bcecf1612) or [vcokltfre's error handler from their bot tutorial](https://vcokltfre.dev/tutorial/12-errors/). Overall, I just recommend ensuring your error handler works above everything else.